# CAS "INVALID_SERVICE" exception when matching suplied and original service (both are the same)

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, cas

I have a CAS system for authenticate some applications by SSO withing CAS protocol. 
All apps can authenticate in CAS by a LDAP provider. I tried to add some differents authentications origins for each application, more specifically their own database.

When I add the identifiers/names for the requires authentication handlers in each service definition (https://apereo.github.io/cas/development/services/Configuring-Service-Required-AuthN.html#configure-service-required-authentication).
The apps can't validate the ticket because CAS always response: "[INVALID_SERVICE] The ticket not match supplied service". But the both services (the suplied and the original) are the same, as you can see in next log:

> CAS_AuthenticationException thrown CAS URL:
>   https://mycasserver.or/cas/p3/serviceValidate?service=http%3A%2F%2Fxxx.xx.x.xxx%2Fwp-login.php%3Fredirect_to%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fxxx.xx.x.xxx%252Fwp-admin%252F%26reauth%3D1&ticket=ST-19--K-ObBsa-WssIZQ56Ev-WCT26FAubuntuserver
>   Authentication failure: Ticket not validated Reason: [INVALID_SERVICE]
>   CAS error: The ticket 'ST-19--K-ObBsa-WssIZQ56Ev-WCT26FAubuntuserver'
>   not match supplied service. The original service was
>   'http://xxx.xx.x.xxx/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fxxx.xx.x.xxx%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1'
>   and the suplied service was
>   'http://xxx.xx.x.xxx/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fxxx.xx.x.xxx%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1'.
>   CAS response: The ticket
>   'ST-19--K-ObBsa-WssIZQ56Ev-WCT26FAubuntuserver' not match supplied
>   service. The original service was
>   'http://xxx.xx.x.xxx/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fxxx.xx.x.xxx%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1'
>   and the original service was
>   'http://xxx.xx.x.xxx/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fxxx.xx.x.xxx%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1'.

My complete service deffinition is:

```
 {
    "id" : 109,
    "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.support.oauth.services.OAuthRegisteredService",
    "serviceId" : "^http://xxx.xx.x.xxx/.*",
    "clientId" : "45rtXXXXXXXXX5d5hfg2gui",
    "clientSecret" : "XXXXXXXXXXXa36j7esahr51478268XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "name" : "My App",
    "description" : "My APP description",
    "evaluationOrder" : 1,
    "bypassApprovalPrompt": true,
    "attributeReleasePolicy" : {
        "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.ReturnAllowedAttributeReleasePolicy",
        "allowedAttributes" : [
            "java.util.ArrayList",
                ["sn",
                "cn",
                "principalLdapDn",
                "givenName",
                "email",
                "uid",
                "authenticationMethod"]
        ]
    },
    "accessStrategy" : {
        "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceAccessStrategy",
        "unauthorizedRedirectUrl" : "http://mycasserver.or/cas/error",
        "enabled" : true,
        "ssoEnabled" : true,
        "requiredAttributes" : {
          "@class" : "java.util.HashMap",
          "authenticationMethod" : [ "java.util.HashSet", [ "ldap", "database" ] ]
        }
    },
    "requiredHandlers" : [ "java.util.HashSet", ["ldap", "database"] ]
}
```

Here my configuration of ldap and database in 'cas.properties' file:

```
# LDAP Authentication
cas.authn.ldap[0].ldapUrl=ldap://xxx.xx.x.xx:389
cas.authn.ldap[0].baseDn=dc=ldap,dc=myorganization,dc=com
cas.authn.ldap[0].searchFilter=uid={user}
cas.authn.ldap[0].bindDn=cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=myorganization,dc=com
cas.authn.ldap[0].bindCredential=mypass
cas.authn.ldap[0].useSsl=false
cas.authn.ldap[0].name=ldap
cas.authn.ldap[0].order=0

# Database Authentication
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].user=adminuser
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].password=adminpassword
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].driverClass=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].url=jdbc:mysql://xxx.xx.x.xx:3306/mydatabse
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect

cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].sql=SELECT * FROM mydatabse.users WHERE username=?
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].fieldPassword=password
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].name=database
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].order=1
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].passwordEncoder.type=org.example.cas.myCustomPasswordEncoder
```

Comment: Does it work if you use a generic service descriptor like `"serviceId" : "^http://.*"`?

Comment: Thanks for the response @KellenMurphy. I just try your proposal and the result is always the same exception, the suplied and the original service not matching but are the same.